# what is the best way to start gunicorn for django application

Tags: python, django, gunicorn

I have an api application running with 3 workers in gunicorn. A mobile application periodically sends the location to the server. I'm getting crash complaints I'm thinking there's a lot of simonormal requests going on.
If I am not mistaken I can only handle 3 simultaneous requests.

my gunicorn command line

```
gunicorn taxithe.wsgi: application -b 0.0.0.0:8000 --workers 3 --log-level = info
```

I was wondering if there is a way to improve the performance of my command line?

Remembering that my machine only has a CPU

Comment: true, you can only handle 3 simultaneous requests, but if each requests needs e.g. 100ms to resolve and requests 4 and 5 arrive within these 100ms, they won't be dropped, they will just wait for a worker to free (at most 100ms). So the question is: do you know for sure the crashes are related to the server load? Use `htop` on your server to check the memory load and cpu load of your workers, usually the number of workers is memory limited. If you have free memory add workers.

Comment: also if the mobile client crashes because an api request fails, the guy who programmed the mobile app did a bad job :-) It shouldn't crash, it should queue the API call and retry.

Comment: i see in this article https://medium.com/building-the-system/gunicorn-3-means-of-concurrency-efbb547674b7 you will start with commands --worker-class=gevent --worker-connections=1000 and this start with 1000 pseud-threads in each worker. But his recomend if application is  I/O bounded. API application is I/O bounded?

Comment: It really depends on what your application does when it processes the request. More often than not, if it writes to the database, it's the database that will be the bottleneck. Adding pseudo-threads won't help since they would all be waiting on the db. Check your db settings, how many simultaneous connections does it open? And do you allow for reusing connections?

Comment: yes i use database. i use the postgres in another server and use the default configuration this running in docker. I will change max_connections of course i will need power in my machine of postgres server. Thank guy

Comment: Read [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/databases/#persistent-connections) also. The default value of `0` for `CONN_MAX_AGE` is really not optimal.